# .htaccess redirect question mark with no parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have several URLs with question marks that need to be removed.  For example, I need to redirect this URL:

```
http://example.net/?/services
```

To this URL:

```
http://example.net/services
```

I have many more like this, so I would like something that can catch everything with the question mark and properly redirect it.  Many of the answers I found were trying to use `QUERY_STRING` as the condition for the rewrite, but without parameters this does not help. After some digging I found a `RewiteCond` that works, but the `RewriteRule` redirects to the homepage, rather than the URL without the question mark. What I have currently is this:

```
# Remove question mark from string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index\.php)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The first block is the rewrite that I have so far, and the next two are for the CMS url routing. What seems to be happening is that my rewrite in the first block is not keeping the rest of the url.  I have tried several combinations and can't seem to figure out how to keep the rest of the url intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Many of the answers I found were trying to use QUERY_STRING as the condition for the rewrite, but without parameters this does not help.

Yes, this is exactly what the first URL, with a question mark, contains. So, I'm not sure why "this does not help"? In the URL `http://example.net/?/services`, `/services` is the query string. Whether there are key/value pairs (ie. "parameters") is irrelevant.

To redirect URLs of the form `http://example.net/?/services`, that consist of no URL-path and only a query string, try something like:

```
# Remove question mark from string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/(.+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R,L]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the last matched *CondPattern* (ie. `(.+)`, which captures `services`). This assumes that the query string (after the `?`) always starts with a slash, as in your example. (Incidentally, this is also what your front controller is doing, in reverse, so I assume it must be correct.)

The trailing `?` on the *substitution* removes the original query string from the request.

Make sure you clear your browser cache, as any earlier/erroneous 301s will have been cached by the browser.

If this is intended to be a permanent (301) redirect then change `R` to `R=301`, but only when you are sure it's working OK.